# Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless, api-gateway

I have delivered aws serverless (LAmbda, API GW & DynamoDB), but during the developers test they have faced the following error with their 'Postman' utility:

```
{

    "message": "Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. 
               Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. 
               Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. 
               Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date'          
               header. 
               Authorization=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

I have checked the cloudwatch logs but I didn't found anything and I assume that mean the request didn't reached the API endpoint, I don't know why.

Actually, I need to find out whether this error happening because of the Postman parameters or api endpoints.

P.S. Lambda code was developed using Python

Please advise.

Comment: We need more information to help you. Let's start with: does it work for you?

Comment: Can you run your Lambda function directly?

Comment: No, I can't run the Lambda function directly, the developer run it through the Postman.

If you have questions or questions list, please drop them here and I will get all the answers to you.

Answer (score 33):

*The errors are self-explanatory.* No they are not. According the API [Gateway troubleshooting docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-troubleshoot-403-forbidden/), the error message:

> Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header. Authorization=allow

indicates that the **resource path doesn't exist**. Check your url and make sure you're accessing the correct endpoint.

Comment: will also see this error message if the http method you are trying to execute does not live in the resource path on api gateway as well

Comment: In my case my issue was that I didn't have a {proxy+} sub-resource in the REST API Gateway. So my root would work, but any sub-paths would not. My resource for the sub-path did indeed not exist. If you're using a VPC link don't forget to add {proxy} to your endpoint URL.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this error when deployment was done using terraform. For some reason we have to go through AWS console and deploy the API to get rid of this message.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).